# Lightbox 2 Just Opens Up Image as a new page

Tags: jquery, lightbox2

I'm trying to figure out how to get Lightbox2 to work inside of the framework of [my site](http://www.negative-g.com) and I set up a test page.  When you click on the photos (the thumbnails) on the page it opens up the large image in a page of its own instead of a lightbox.  Here is a [link to a test page](http://www.negative-g.com/test/joyland-amusement-park-2013-1.htm).  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Always take a look at the console when you have problems. There are some 404 errors there that explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your links to both the jQuery library and the lightbox plugin do not work.

Check these file locations and make sure that they work;

```
<script src="http://www.negative-g.com/lightbox/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.negative-g.com/lightbox/js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
```

You have probably not uploaded them to the location specified, or put the wrong location in the script src.

Also your css files are not loading either.

Comment: Thanks...how do I load the CSS files...I'm kind of new at CSS?

Comment: @PaulDrabek You just need to make sure that the path to your css files is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your test page isn't loading the necessary resources. Try checking that your paths are configured correctly.

```
GET http://www.negative-g.com/test/.../lightbox/css/lightbox.css 404 (Not Found) joyland-amusement-park-2013-1.htm:24
GET http://www.negative-g.com/lightbox/js/lightbox-2.6.min.js 404 (Not Found) joyland-amusement-park-2013-1.htm:55
GET http://www.negative-g.com/lightbox/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js 404 (Not Found) joyland-amusement-park-2013-1.htm:55
GET http://www.negative-g.com/test/.../lightbox/css/screen.css 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Ok I fixed the paths...I made them absolute instead of relative.  Still doing the same thing.  Thanks a ton.